# Google Drive have a folder/file in both private and public

Tags: google-drive

I've my documents in Google Drive/Docs neatly organised in structured folder system. For not cluttering email inboxes purposes I now would like to share the content of 1 single private folder by putting it in the public directory. If possible I'd like to do this without duplicating the content.

Is it possible to organise files in Google Drive to that they have 2 tags/folders attached to them - 1 private and 1 public? Is there another way to quickly share/link a folder to my public folder without actually moving it away from my private to my public folder?

Comment: Sorry, i'm a little confused. From what i understand, you want to change the permission of specific sub-folders in root folder?

Comment: Yes indeed, so for example I've:
/Folder/Subfolder

And now I want to have this subfolder in the original place AND also in the /Public/

Comment: You don't have to duplicate the folder in Public to share it. If you go to http://drive.google.com, you can manually change the share settings of each particular file folder by right clicking on it, and going to Share > Share. Then you can choose to specifically share it with certain people via email, make it private, or make the entire folder Public also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to duplicate the folder in Public to share it. If you go to drive.google.com, you can manually change the share settings of each particular file folder by right clicking on it, and going to Share > Share. Then you can choose to specifically share it with certain people via email, make it private, or make the entire folder Public also.